# Add plus/minus buttons to table cell LibGDX

Tags: java, layout, libgdx, scene2d

I am looking for a way to add plus and minus buttons to table cells in LibGDX.
I'm trying to do something like this image:

[image]

I noticed that the **uiskin** files I'm using contain plus and minus buttons (right next to the checkbox) which will do just fine ([uiskin.png](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.png)).

Any tips on how I can add those to my table and make it so they increase/decrease the integer value in that table cell?

I've added a rudimentary sample code with an indication of what I want to do:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));

    Table table = new Table(skin);
    table.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        table.add(Integer.toString(i)); //Somehow add plus/minus buttons left 
                                        //and right that increase/decrease the integer value
        table.row();
    }

    stage.addActor(table);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}


@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}
```

This is just some example code, but if it works here I will certainly be able to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: First, you need to create 2 `ImageButton`, let's say `minusButton` and `plusButton`. Just look at the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html) to see how to create them from your skin. Then, you only need to add these buttons to your table : `table.add(plusButton);` `table.add(minusButton);`

Comment: @vdlmrc  I tried that already, but there are two problems with that: 
1) uiskin does not seem to have a method to retrieve those buttons (for example you can call CheckBox for a checkbox, but I can't find any reference to the plus/minus buttons in the file description) and 2) if I create my own buttons and add them to the table, then I can't find a way to reference the cell that's right next to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an array to store your number values. It's not good practice to use your View (table cells) to store your Model (number values), and besides, Label cells store a String, not an integer, so it would be inconvenient.

```
private int[] tableData = new int[10];
```

Now you need a button that can be associated with a row in your data. Here's one way Create a subclass of ImageButton that can take a row number and mode (subtract or add).

```
public class IncrementButton extends ImageButton {

    public final int rowNumber;
    public final boolean decrement;

    public IncrementButton (Skin skin, String styleName, int rowNumber, boolean decrement){
        super(skin, styleName);
        this.rowNumber = rowNumber;
        this.decrement = decrement;
    }
}
```

The plus and minus images in the uiskin atlas you're using are called "tree-minus" and "tree-plus". You need an ImageButton style for each of these that uses one of these as the `imageUp` property. (`imageUp` is used as a default if you don't define images for other states such as `imageDown`.) You can add these to uiskin.json:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    plus: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, imageUp: tree-plus },
    minus: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, imageUp: tree-minus }
},
```

Now you can create a ChangeListener for these buttons that will modify the numbers in the data and update the table accordingly. And then set it all up:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/uiskin.json"));

final Table table = new Table(skin);
final Label[] labels = new Label[tableData.length]; //keep references to the labels for updating them.

final ChangeListener incrementListner = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        IncrementButton incrementButton = (IncrementButton)actor;
        int row = incrementButton.rowNumber;
        tableData[row] += incrementButton.decrement ? -1 : 1;
        labels[row].setText(Integer.toString(tableData[row]));
    }
};

table.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
for(int i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++){
    IncrementButton decrementButton = new IncrementButton(skin, "minus", i, true);
    decrementButton.addListener(incrementListner);
    IncrementButton incrementButton = new IncrementButton(skin, "plus", i, false);
    incrementButton.addListener(incrementListner);

    table.add(decrementButton);
    labels[i] = table.add(Integer.toString(i)).getActor();//Add number label and keep reference to it in labels array for the change listener to look up
    table.add(incrementButton);
    table.row();
}

stage.addActor(table);

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

If you want to set min and max values for the data, then you need some arrays for the plus buttons and minus buttons (similar to the `labels` array) so the change listener can look up and disable/enable the buttons accordingly when a limit is hit.